# Differences between AWS CloudWatch alarms created by Console vs. CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I Have created simple AWS cloudwatch alarm with console. It is triggered by metric "Cognito-By UserPoolAndUserPoolClient-SignInSuccesses". It works as supposed and sends an email via SNS Topic.
I tried to create same alarm with CLI, but it doesn't work. Alarm doesn't get triggered. I compared in console what is difference between those two alarms. When creating alarm with console in metric selection I see metric with information "UserPool" and "UserPoolClient". When using CLI command there isn't parameters to set those two. How could I configure new alarm with CLI so that it is identical to one created in console?

CLI command:

aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name NewSignupAlarm --alarm-description "New Signup have been done." --alarm-actions arn:aws:sns:eu-west-3:681278469643:NewTestTopic --metric-name SignUpSuccesses --namespace AWS/Cognito --statistic Sum --period 300 --unit Count --evaluation-periods 1 --threshold 0 --comparison-operator GreaterThanThreshold --profile user3
[image: These are missing when created with CLI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These values are dimensions on the metric. You can specify them with the `--dimensions` parameter, like this:

```
--dimensions Name=UserPool,Value=eu-west-3_... Name=UserPoolClient,Value=117...
```

Make sure the values are exact, I used `...` just to illustrate the usage.

See here for more info on all different parameters that you may need to set if you want the alarm be the same as the one created in the console:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-alarm.html

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. With dimensions added both alarms looks now identical. For some reason alarm created with CLI doesn't get triggered same time than other. I  still have to investigate that further.

Comment: Now my CLI alarm works like the one created in console. Differences were those two dimensions (UserPool and UserPoolClient). 
Also I had to add  "--TreateMissingData Missing"